# How to set the background color on the last row in a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am building a custom control and want to add a feature where the background color of the last row on a DataGrid can be set.

My first issue is how to Select the last row on a DataGrid.

The second issue is how to set the background color to that entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code for the custom control in which `LastRowColor` can be set. I have used `LoadingRow` event to set the Last row color.

```csharp
class DatagridEx : DataGrid
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty LastRowColourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LastRowColour), typeof(Brush), typeof(DatagridEx), new PropertyMetadata());

    public Brush LastRowColour
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(LastRowColourProperty);
        set => SetValue(LastRowColourProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnLoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoadingRow(e);

        var index = Items.IndexOf(e.Row.DataContext);
        if (index == Items.Count - 1)
        {
            e.Row.Background = LastRowColour;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in the xaml code like this:

```
<local:DatagridEx x:Name="dgr" LastRowColour="Red">
    ...        
</local:DatagridEx>
```